# How to handle simple authentication with Azure (with local user accounts)?

Tags: azure, authentication

I would like to build a very simple Angular 4 app with a WepApi Service as backend.

I would also like to have users register with my app (the basic "create user" - "validate email" - "log in" workflow).

The user/passwords should be stored with my own app (SQL database).

Where would I go for this very basic information? I am highly frustrated with all the "look it's so easy, you can use ANY social media account! Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft! Just three clicks and all is super-secure with OAuth" talk.

Please point me in the right direction - finding this very basic information seems impossible to me.

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is :

> Step 1 : call facebook auth from client it returns me **id**,
>   **profile** etc,
>
> Step 2 : then I send **fb id** to the server (deployed on azure), where it
>   checks if this **fb id** already exists in database it redirects to login,
>   otherwise it creates a new user

you can also authenticate fb token on server side also for more security.

for login with facebook scenario [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837550/authentication-in-rest-node-js-server-using-an-android-client-with-facebook-log/44845764#44845764) question might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Azure App Service** along with **Easy Authentication** as it allows you to configure your app along with Facebook/Twitter/Google/MSA.

For Starters see this:

1. [How authentication works in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#how-authentication-works-in-app-service)
2. [How authorization works in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#a-nameauthorizationahow-authorization-works-in-app-service)

The following tutorials show how to configure App Service to use different authentication providers:

- [How to configure your app to use **Azure Active Directory login**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)
- [How to configure your app to use **Facebook login**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication)
- [How to configure your app to use **Google login**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication)
- [How to configure your app to use **Microsoft Account login**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication)
- [How to configure your app to use **Twitter** login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-twitter-authentication)

The above steps do not require you to write any code. However if you need to authorize then you need to handle that in your application.

The above should get you started. Also see this thread where I shared insights on how you can query Facebook: [Correct Facebook Graph Api Video Insitghts Request PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782409/correct-facebook-graph-api-video-insitghts-request-php-sdk/44783464#44783464)

I also have a blogpost on this here: 
[Azure App Service: Using Easy Auth to query Facebook information via Graph API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/06/08/using-easy-auth-to-query-facebook-information-via-graph-api/)